# Visualized Imputation of 2D Sample Space With Saturation Corresponding to Confidence?

Tags: confidence-interval, data-visualization, expectation-maximization, data-imputation, exploratory-data-analysis

I want to visualize a 2D sample space imputed from a 2D scatter of measurements.  Something like a 2D `hexbin` color histogram would work if it were enhanced in the following ways:

- The number of samples in a bin determines the saturation of the color -- corresponding to the confidence obtained with more samples.
- The hue of the bin is the maximum likelihood or expected value measurement for that bin.
- Bins with no or very few samples would enjoy higher confidence, hence saturation, based on imputation from nearby bins with higher confidence (number of samples).

This would require a 2D color map with one dimension a range of hues and the other dimension a range of saturations.

Is there published work along these lines, preferrably with an existing software library?

Answer (score 1):

The paper [Value-Suppressing Uncertainty Palettes](https://github.com/uwdata/papers-vsup/) may be what you want. The link is to the github site which links to the paper itself and other materials.

The idea is to *suppress* values with high uncertainty by desaturating the color. The paper discussing two techniques, with the new technique "VSUP" being to not only desaturate the color but also use a coarser color map for the hues of more uncertain values.

[image]